# Python opcua module CancelledError

Tags: python, opc-ua

I am currently trying to connect to an OPC UA server, which was set up on my local device as a test environment. The server was not set up by me, it is not implemented in python (think it might be json).
I wanted to connect to it using the following code:

```
from opcua import Client
from opcua import ua

url = 'https://{MyPCsName}:8443/opcua'

client = Client(url)
client.connect()
```

However an error was raised:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CancelledError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-b87841b743a5> in <module>
      5 
      6 client = Client(url)
----> 7 client.connect()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opcua\client\client.py in connect(self)
    272         self.connect_socket()
    273         try:
--> 274             self.send_hello()
    275             self.open_secure_channel()
    276             try:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opcua\client\client.py in send_hello(self)
    314         Send OPC-UA hello to server
    315         """
--> 316         ack = self.uaclient.send_hello(self.server_url.geturl(), self.max_messagesize, self.max_chunkcount)
    317 
    318         # TODO: Handle ua.UaError

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py in send_hello(self, url, max_messagesize, max_chunkcount)
    270 
    271     def send_hello(self, url, max_messagesize=0, max_chunkcount=0):
--> 272         return self._uasocket.send_hello(url, max_messagesize, max_chunkcount)
    273 
    274     def open_secure_channel(self, params):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py in send_hello(self, url, max_messagesize, max_chunkcount)
    188         binmsg = uatcp_to_binary(ua.MessageType.Hello, hello)
    189         self._socket.write(binmsg)
--> 190         ack = future.result(self.timeout)
    191         return ack
    192 

~\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    435 
    436             if self._state in [CANCELLED, CANCELLED_AND_NOTIFIED]:
--> 437                 raise CancelledError()
    438             elif self._state == FINISHED:
    439                 return self.__get_result()

CancelledError:
```

I **skimmed** through the Git repository https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua and the "documentation" https://python-opcua.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html (which was more or less a copy of the source code, as I understand ...), yet I could not find a way to troubleshoot the occurring error.

From the server side, things should be ok, as I can access the server under `'https://{MyPCsName}:8443/opcua'` just fine on UaExpert.
Really hoping for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error it seems the Python client is trying to connect using the UA Binary TCP transport but you have been given an HTTPS endpoint URL.

Perhaps you need to use a different endpoint URL to connect to this server? Maybe it’s `opc.tcp://{PCName}:4840/opcua` if it’s using the default port.

Comment: An attempt to connect to connect to the default port gives me a `ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061]`. I'll inquire if there is a opc.tcp adress available.
Is there a workaround to connect úsing https?

Comment: Your insight, that UA Binary TCP transport is the default (and apparently currently only) connection method, helped me considerably. After I requested the tcp address of the server I was able to connect just fine using `url = 'opc.tcp://{PCName}:{port}/{path}'` . Thank you so much!

Comment: The UA TCP binary transport is the only one for which support is mandatory. The HTTPS transport is not commonly used in the real world (for OPC UA, not in general obviously). If the library you are using didn't implement HTTPS support at all I wouldn't be surprised.